# Typescript refactor switch statement

Tags: typescript

I have a switch statement but the content on each case its very similar, basically the only difference is the URL with the select properties in the REST call, and the .then when the json result is converted to a specific collection of specific types.

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { IWebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
import { IListItem} from "./models/IListItem";
import { IFactory } from "./IFactory";
import { INewsListItem } from "./models/INewsListItem";
import { IDirectoryListItem } from "./models/IDirectoryListItem";
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from "./models/IAnnouncementListItem";

export class ListItemFactory implements IFactory {
    // private _listItems: IListItem[];
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): Promise<any[]> {
        switch(listName) {
            case "GenericList":
                let items: IListItem[];
                // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: IListItem[] }) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.value));
                    return items=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        {
                            // key: v.id,
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title
                        }
                    ));
                });
            case "News":
                let newsitems: INewsListItem[];
                // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Created By,Modified By,newsheader,newsbody,expiryDate`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: INewsListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: INewsListItem[] }) => {
                    return newsitems=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            newsheader: v.newsheader,
                            newsbody: v.newsbody,
                            expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                        }
                    ));
                });
            case "Announcements":
                let announcementitems: IAnnouncementListItem[];
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Created,Author/Title,Modified,Editor/Title,announcementBody,expiryDate&$expand=Author,Editor`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }) => {
                    return announcementitems=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            announcementBody: v.announcementBody,
                            expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                        }
                    ));
                });
            case "Directory":
                let directoryitems: IDirectoryListItem[];
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IDirectoryListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: IDirectoryListItem[] }) => {
                    return directoryitems=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        {
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            firstName: v.firstName,
                            lastName: v.lastName,
                            mobileNumber: v.mobileNumber,
                            internalNumber: v.internalNumber
                        }
                    ));
                });
            default:
                break;
            }
      }
}
```

Update 1

Based on the answer I changed the IFactory.ts

```
import { IListItem } from "./models/IListItem";
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { ListItemFactory } from "./ListItemFactory";
export  interface IFactory {

    getItems<K extends keyof ListItemFactory['handlers']>(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: K): Promise<ReturnType<ListItemFactory['handlers'][K]['process']>> ;


    //getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): Promise<any[]>;
}
```

And the  ListItemFactory.ts

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { IWebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
import { IListItem} from "./models/IListItem";
import { IFactory } from "./IFactory";
import { INewsListItem } from "./models/INewsListItem";
import { IDirectoryListItem } from "./models/IDirectoryListItem";
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from "./models/IAnnouncementListItem";

export class ListItemFactory implements IFactory {
    private handlers = {
        GenericList : {
            url: (siteUrl: string, listName: string) => `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
            async process(result: any)  {
                const json: { value: IListItem[] } = result;
                return json.value.map((v,i)=>({
                    // key: v.id,
                    id: v.Id,
                    title: v.Title,
                    created: v.Created,
                    createdby: v.Author.Title,
                    modified: v.Modified,
                    modifiedby: v.Editor.Title
                }));
            }
        },
        News: {
            url: (siteUrl: string, listName: string) => `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Created By,Modified By,newsheader,newsbody,expiryDate`,
            async process(result: any) {
                const json: { value: INewsListItem[] } = result;
                return json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                    { 
                        id: v.Id,
                        title: v.Title,
                        created: v.Created,
                        createdby: v.Author.Title,
                        modified: v.Modified,
                        modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                        newsheader: v.newsheader,
                        newsbody: v.newsbody,
                        expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                    }
                ));
            }
        },
        Announcements: {
            url: (siteUrl: string, listName: string) => `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Created,Author/Title,Modified,Editor/Title,announcementBody,expiryDate&$expand=Author,Editor`,
            async process(result: any) {
                const json: { value: IAnnouncementListItem[] } = result;
                return json.value.map((v,i)=>({ 
                    id: v.Id,
                    title: v.Title,
                    created: v.Created,
                    createdby: v.Author.Title,
                    modified: v.Modified,
                    modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                    announcementBody: v.announcementBody,
                    expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                }));
            }
        },
        Directory: {
            url: (siteUrl: string, listName: string) => `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
            process(result: any) {
                const json: { value: IDirectoryListItem[] } = result;
                return json.value.map((v,i)=>({
                    id: v.Id,
                    title: v.Title,
                    created: v.Created,
                    createdby: v.Author.Title,
                    modified: v.Modified,
                    modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                    firstName: v.firstName,
                    lastName: v.lastName,
                    mobileNumber: v.mobileNumber,
                    internalNumber: v.internalNumber
                }));
            }
        }
    };

    public async getItems<K extends keyof ListItemFactory['handlers']>(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: K): Promise<ReturnType<ListItemFactory['handlers'][K]['process']>> {
        var h = this.handlers[listName];
        const response = await requester.get(
            h.url(siteUrl, listName),
            SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                    "odata-version": ""
                }
        });
        var json = response.json();
        return h.process(json) as any;
    }
}
```

However I get this errors

```
[19:42:56] Error - typescript - src/webparts/factoryMethod/components/IFactory.ts(5,122): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReturnType'.
[19:42:56] Error - typescript - src/webparts/factoryMethod/components/ListItemFactory.ts(80,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReturnType'.
[19:42:56] Error - typescript - src/webparts/factoryMethod/components/IFactory.ts(5,122): error TS4057: Return type of method from exported interface has or is using private name 'ReturnType'.
[19:42:56] Error - typescript - src/webparts/factoryMethod/components/ListItemFactory.ts(80,135): error TS4055: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using private name 'ReturnType'.
[19:42:56] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 2.93 s
[19:42:56] Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 2.06 s
 TypeScript error(s) occurred.
```

Comment: Wrap it in a function and add arguments to it. The arguments should be the things that are different between the snippets.

Comment: `ReturnType` is something from TS 2.8ish. If you are using 2.7 you can't do that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take out the common parts from each switch and move the different parts in a map object. The uncommon parts seem to be the url and how the result is processed.

Also we can do better with the return type and the list type. We restrict the key to only be one of the supported values, and to have a return type specific to the `listName` passed in.

```
export class ListItemFactory implements IFactory {
    handlers = {
        GenericList : {
            url: (siteUrl: string, listName: string) => `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
            async process(result: any)  {
                const json: { value: IListItem[] } = result;
                return json.value.map((v,i)=>({
                    // key: v.id,
                    id: v.Id,
                    title: v.Title,
                    created: v.Created,
                    createdby: v.Author.Title,
                    modified: v.Modified,
                    modifiedby: v.Editor.Title
                }));
            }
        },
        News: {
            url: (siteUrl: string, listName: string) => `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Created By,Modified By,newsheader,newsbody,expiryDate`,
            async process(result: any) {
                const json: { value: INewsListItem[] } = result;
                return json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                    { 
                        id: v.Id,
                        title: v.Title,
                        created: v.Created,
                        createdby: v.Author.Title,
                        modified: v.Modified,
                        modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                        newsheader: v.newsheader,
                        newsbody: v.newsbody,
                        expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                    }
                ));
            }
        },
        Announcements: {
            url: (siteUrl: string, listName: string) => `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Created,Author/Title,Modified,Editor/Title,announcementBody,expiryDate&$expand=Author,Editor`,
            async process(result: any) {
                const json: { value: IAnnouncementListItem[] } = result;
                return json.value.map((v,i)=>({ 
                    id: v.Id,
                    title: v.Title,
                    created: v.Created,
                    createdby: v.Author.Title,
                    modified: v.Modified,
                    modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                    announcementBody: v.announcementBody,
                    expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                }));
            }
        },
        Directory: {
            url: (siteUrl: string, listName: string) => `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
            process(result: any) {
                const json: { value: IDirectoryListItem[] } = result;
                return json.value.map((v,i)=>({
                    id: v.Id,
                    title: v.Title,
                    created: v.Created,
                    createdby: v.Author.Title,
                    modified: v.Modified,
                    modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                    firstName: v.firstName,
                    lastName: v.lastName,
                    mobileNumber: v.mobileNumber,
                    internalNumber: v.internalNumber
                }));
            }
        }
    }
    public async getItems<K extends keyof ListItemFactory['handlers']>(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: K): Promise<ReturnType<ListItemFactory['handlers'][K]['process']>> {
        var h = this.handlers[listName];
        const response = await requester.get(
            h.url(siteUrl, listName),
            SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                    "odata-version": ""
                }
        });
        var json = response.json();
        return h.process(json) as any;
    }
}

let fact = new ListItemFactory();
let requester!: SPHttpClient;
let siteUrl = ''
var genList = fact.getItems(requester, siteUrl, 'GenericList'); // Promise<Promise<{id: any;title: any;created: any;createdby: any;modified: any;modifiedby: any;}[]>>
var dirList = fact.getItems(requester, siteUrl, 'Directory'); // Promise<{id: any;title: any;created: any;createdby: any;modified: any;modifiedby: any;firstName: any;lastName: any;mobileNumber: any;internalNumber: any;}[]>
```

**Edit**

A bit of explanation on the signature of `getItems`. The method is now generic, with a type parameter `K` that MUST be a key of the handlers object. This  restriction is done using `keyof T` which gives a type representing the public keys of `T` and `ListItemFactory['handlers']` which is a type query and gives us the type of the `handlers` field, so putting it all we get `K extends keyof ListItemFactory['handlers']`.

Now the parameter `listName` can only have a value of `'GenericList'`, `'News'`, `'Announcements'` or `'Directory'`, and when we call the metod, depending on value passed in `K` will be the [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) type representing one of these values.

We now want to tie the return value of `getItems` to the return type of the `process` function of the `listName` passed in. We have the `listName` as a string literal type in `K` so to get the type of the handler, we can use a type query: `ListItemFactory['handlers'][K]` drilling down to get the type of the `process` function we get `ListItemFactory['handlers'][K]['process']`.

To get the return type of this function type we use the built-in conditional type `ReturnType<T>`. `ReturnType<()=> number>` will be `number`, the type does what it's name implies if we pass in a function type we get it's return value

Putting it all together we get a return type of `Promise<ReturnType<ListItemFactory['handlers'][K]['process']>>`

**Edit**

For 2.4.2 you can't use conditional types (they are only available since 2.8). 
You can just use `any` as the return type as in your original code (not ideal but this is what we can do in 2.4.2, ideally you should try to update to a newer version):

```
public async getItems<K extends keyof ListItemFactory['handlers']>(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: K): Promise<any>
```

Comment: can you dissect the getItems signature and explain it please, its confusing for me.

Comment: also, why requester!: ?

Comment: @LuisValencia I'm using strict and not initializing the `requester` variable causes an error `!` is a definite assignment operator to tell the compiler not to worry about it. I'll explain the signature in a second.

Comment: @LuisValencia added an explanation, let me know it something is unclear

Comment: thanks for the great explanation, will test it later when I get home

Comment: @LuisValencia caveat: the code compiles, but I did not test it extensively, if you have any problems let me know.

Comment: I have the following 2 errors, am I missing an import? [19:39:46] Error - typescript - src/webparts/factoryMethod/components/ListItemFactory.ts(80,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReturnType'.
[19:39:46] Error - typescript - src/webparts/factoryMethod/components/ListItemFactory.ts(80,135): error TS4055: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using private name 'ReturnType'.

Comment: Better, see my Update in the original question, where I tried to implement your code, but not compiling for me.

Comment: @LuisValencia what version of Typescript are you using? The code above requires 2.8 or above (the current version is 2.9) I can adapt to a lower version, but I need to know which one and some of the features may be lost.

Comment: this is a sharepoint framework project, apparently the yeoman generator needs 2.4.2 https://screencast.com/t/Q8002L1dB5z

Comment: @LuisValencia it's too bad you are stuck on such an old version, I will update the answer tomorrow. It's already nigh time in my neck of the woods and I am on the phone :-) Most of it should work, except for the smart return type.

Comment: still watiing, if you can!

Comment: @LuisValencia sorry I forgot to add a comment, I edited the answer for 2.4 a while ago :)

Comment: I thought ReturnType would not  be available in 2.4

Comment: @LuisValencia It's not, the valid signature for 2.4 is at the bottom of the post: `public async getItems<K extends keyof ListItemFactory['handlers']>(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: K): Promise<any>` You need to replace it in the original code

Comment: @LuisValencia could you also award the bounty if the answer was helpful. 10x